# Asus E200HA RAM upgrade

Tags: memory, motherboard, upgrade

It's been known to me that RAM on Asus E200HA is soldered within the motherboard, thus not upgradable. `lshw` shows though there are two slots optional but only one used. The question is: is there a way to use that empty slot in a user friendly manner, or is this info just useless?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your system has actually wired the second memory channel from the CPU to a DIMM slot that information is useless to you. All it means is that your CPU has pins to connect to a second memory module, not that you have space to fit one.

Your [motherboard manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeeBook/0409_E10745_E200HA_C.pdf) has no mention of memory upgrades, and [Mr Memory](https://www.mrmemory.co.uk/memory-ram-upgrades/asus/laptop/vivobook-e200ha)and [Crucial](https://uk.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asus/vivobook-e200ha) both state that your memory is not upgradable.

---

The following two images from [Chipbay.uk](https://www.chipbay.uk/product/genuine-asus-e200ha-laptop-intel-motherboard-60nl0070-mb1150/) show your motherboard in detail. Your current 4GB of memory will be the two chips on the left of the CPU on the top image and the right of the CPU area on the bottom image.

You have no place for a DIMM to be fitted, nor do you have any area where extra chips could be soldered.

You have a single channel of RAM connected and no physical way to connect more RAM or to replace the current RAM without first desoldering the current chips. Getting a professional to do the work, or even to source replacements that *might* work, would likely cost more than the computer is worth.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The ["motherboard manual"](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeeBook/0409_E10745_E200HA_C.pdf) has no mention of motherboard. Aside from BIOS USB-upgrade there is no mention of anything internal. 
Retailers or the manufacturer stating "not upgradable" is no new info.

Comment: When I said "user friendly" I should rather have said "superuser friendly". Which means I'm willing to have unconventional ways with the motherboard if there is any possibility not requiring a whole Asus factory at home.

Comment: Regarding your saying that `lshw` output relates to CPU design and not the motherboard I don't know if it is true. If you're sure of it tell so, otherwise it demands further lookup.

Comment: @Multifix updated with images of your motherboard. You have nowhere to fit RAM **at all**. there is no "user friendly" or even "super user friendly" way to do what you want.